# Packaging JavaScript based plug and play application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html, webpack

I am trying to build a plug and play web based application that I should be able to integrate with multiple other web applications (which are developed using AngalurJS\ ExtJS\ ReactJS etc). On click of a button, I should be able to launch a [sliding menu](http://codepen.io/jasonhowmans/pen/dykhL). On this menu, I want to add Twitter like functionality. On the first half of the menu we will have a textbox (with features like autocomplete & hash tags). The second half with show a gird which will show already posted messages.  The panel will be responsible to get and post data to server.

The challenge is, I want to add this functionality to multiple other web applications with minimum configuration\changes. The consuming web applications should be able use this plugin with ease. Certain challenges I see is bootstrap does not play well with ExtJs framework & I may face similar issues with other JavaScript frameworks.

**Questions:**

1. `How can I package this application?` It has a panel with third party plugins (for autocomplete & other features), CSS & JavaScript. I can use web pack or Browserify but I want to keep the solution clean & don't want to add unnecessary dependency.
2. The consumers should be able to consume the bundle\package with ease & just by adding some references (like my bundle, css file, jquery, bootstrap).

I think, I can get the desired result with a simple ReactJs app, which I can bundle using web pack. But this will introduce other dependency. I want to keep the web application lite and simple.

Comment: Just me wondering but how is this related to NodeJS? Is it a frontend and backend? Is it an Express application?
One of the solution is to pack everything in a single html file (including css, images and javascript) and read parameters from the url. But i might be getting what your application is ment to do wrong.

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier: I want to keep things simple & by that I mean, I do not want to add extra dependency. I added nodejs just for managing packages (babel, webpack etc). This application should have both front end and backend. But my question is more towards designing the front end. since this a plug and play app, consumers should be able to add this app with ease.

Comment: Well ok, but i don't see how you could keep your solution simple other than packing all your resources in a single html file. This wouldn't add any dependencies. You would just need to have a gulp/bower/... build script to aceive that. In the past, I worked on a mobile app that proceeded that way to deploy "offline" content to mobile devices and it was great.
Anyways you might need to add more detail and background information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I can use web pack or Browserify but I want to keep the solution clean & don't want to add unnecessary dependency.

I don't understand the problem. Using webpack or browserfy will only add [devDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#devdependencies). You won't ship it. You package won't depend on it. 
You won't be able to avoid using a bundler if you want to bundle it.

> The consumers should be able to consume the bundle\package with ease & just by adding some references (like my bundle, css file, jquery, bootstrap).

If you distribute it via npm (de facto standard in JS), they just regularly import the resources with the correct path (e.g. `node_modules/package/styles.css`).
In npm you could also declare your [peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies) (you mention jquery, bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

**1. How can I package this application?**

- You should minify all your HTML using a build tool like grunt or gulp
- If you want to keep the count of different files low, you can merge all your CSS, HTML and maybe even Images (base64 encoded) into your `module.js`. Ideally you could end up with only delivering a single file.

**2. The consumers should be able to consume the bundle\package with ease & just by adding some references.**

In that case they just need to include the script, like:

```
<script src="app-module.js"></script>
```

---

If you are able to use EcmaScript 2015, you might consider to package your plug-and-play app into a ES6 Module. Define your `module.js` simply as:

```
export var myNumber = 333
export function myFunction() {
  ...
}
```

And on the site, which is consuming your app, you simply add a dependency using the `import` keyword:

```
import * as service from 'module'
console.log(service.myNumber) // 333
```

Read more about [ES6 Modules](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html).